# Auto populate dropdown value not getting submitted when selected through select2 option

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a dropdown in select2, to get the list of customers. When a customer is selected, i am displaying address and contact related to that customer. 
But when i submit these data, value of contact and address is not getting the values at all.

Here is my script

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fetchcontactaddress.js"></script>

    <div class="media-body text-right">
        <h4>Customer</h4>
          <span><select name="customer" class="form-control is-invalid" id="selUser" onChange="showContactAdd(this);" required>
                </select></span>
     </div>

     <div class="row" id="output"> 

             //address and contact for selected customer should display here  

</div>
```

fetchcontactaddress.js

```
function showContactAdd(sel) {
    var cat_id = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;  
    $("#output").html( "" );

    if (cat_id.length > 0 ) {

     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "FetchContactsAdd.php",
            data: "cat_id="+cat_id,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('#output').html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24">');
            },
            success: function(html) {    
                $("#output").html( html );
            }
        });
    }
}
```

FetchContactsAdd.php

```
$cat_id = ($_REQUEST["cat_id"] <> "") ? trim( addslashes($_REQUEST["cat_id"])) : "";
if ($cat_id <> "" ) {
    ?>
 <div class="media-body text-right">
                                                <h4>Contact</h4>
                               <span>  <select name="contact" class="form-control is-invalid" required>

                                        <?php 
  $Scust = "SELECT con_id, fname, lname FROM cust_contacts WHERE status = 'A' AND customer=".$cat_id."";
$Cust = DB_query($Scust);
while($Crow = DB_fetch_array($Cust)) { ?> 
<option value="<?php echo $Crow['con_id']; ?>"><?php echo $Crow['fname'].' '.$Crow['lname']; ?></option>
                                    <?php } ?>


                                    </select>   </span>
                                            </div>


                                            <div class="media-body text-right">
                                                <h4>Address</h4>
                               <span>  <select name="address" class="form-control">

                                        <?php 
  $cadd = "SELECT ad_id, add_name FROM cust_address WHERE status = 'A' AND customer=".$cat_id."";
$cadd1 = DB_query($cadd);
while($carow = DB_fetch_array($cadd1)) { ?> 
<option value="<?php echo $carow['ad_id']; ?>"><?php echo $carow['add_name']; ?></option>
                                    <?php } ?>
 </select></span>
                                            </div>
```

When a customer is selected the value populates, but when i hit submit, it is not taking id values for both address and contact

Comment: Start to debug, have you try to `console.log(cat_id)` ? or the response?

Comment: Yes, It shows proper id and also it displays contacts and address in dropdown respectively. When i submit, contact and address shows blank.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved! I have added 2 jquery files with different versions. 
I have added `$.noConflict(true);` and it worked.